# Asking for personal contact information in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, personal-data

Recently a user asked me to provide my personal email address or Twitter account handle, because he wanted to connect with me offline.

Is sharing such information in comments allowed? If not, what can we do about it?

Comment: I would say that information you _want_ to share should be in your profile and point users to there.

Comment: People can ask what they want. There's no obligation to acceed to their requests though. If you don't want to do it either just ignore the comment or flag it.

Comment: When they ask a question and want additional instructions about specific topic, they can easily start a chat with that person and learn a lot about that problem they have. Additional information about personal e-mails can be told in chat if that person wants. And it ends there. If you put too much personal information into profile page you get another social network and SO ain't that.

Comment: once, I have shared my contact info in chat with one of very kind user here. It proved very helpful then. :)

Comment: I keep a gmail account listed on my profile page on another high-profile help site and I've pointed users there on a small handful of incidences. It comes with the caveat that *'I'm occasionally available at ...'*.

Comment: @KuKeC As I understand it the chat rooms are public for anyone to see. Only those invited can participate but anyone can see it. You should not share contact info in chat that you wish to keep private.

Comment: @D_Bester I agree with you but i think it's better after some discussion share your contact info to person you exchanged several messages about his problem and after that give him personal info rather than putting your contact info into profile and then anyone can contact you without even asking for permission. Maybe this "problem" is a way to develop option "send personal messages" in chat rooms for this kind of situations.

Comment: I've had people look at my profile, see the website and then send me email in the contact form (which actually doesn't only go to me). But the time it happened most recently the person also had posted an issue on one of my github repositories. Which just goes to show there are lots of ways people can find you. In that case it didn't seem creepy, but I could see cases where it would.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## That is completely your decision

What you want to disclose is completely up to you. Some people are more than happy to offer that information for a multitude of reasons.

- off-topic support
- Internet pen pals
- ...

I would say that if you are comfortable offering your personal contacts do so in your profile and point users to there in the comments. If nothing else, it will make updating it more fluid and won't confuse future readers.

Otherwise you could ignore them or politely suggest you are not comfortable giving out that information. As Jon Clements states:

> If they become persistent/pestering by keeping asking or it's noticed they're doing the same with other users then you may wish to consider flagging for a mod and explaining what's going on

Also depending on the need you can always offer chat as well.

Comment: If they become persistent/pestering by keeping asking or it's noticed they're doing the same with other users then you may wish to consider flagging for a mod and explaining what's going on.

Comment: @JonClements Very true

Comment: @JonClements I asked him, why he need that information and soon after he deleted the comment.

Comment: Just some user not understanding how things work.

Comment: I would also add that if you do end up talking with someone through an external system, make sure that you still go back to SO and update questions/answers when appropriate, so that everyone still benefits. It wouldn't be good to ask a question, ask for someone's contact details, communicate with them externally and obtain a solution, and then not answer the question back on SO.

Comment: I would add that if you do choose to give out contact information, write the numbers out for phone and type your email address with spaces and write out the symbols so that screen scrapers have at least some difficulty getting the information.
(ex: Phone: nine nine nine dash nine nine nine nine, or for email: Bob at gmail dot com)

Comment: @CBauer: LOL -- if you think scrapers have any trouble with "Bob at gmail dot com", you're living in 1999. :-) (And: Um. Sorry, Bob.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Even in 1999, I'm pretty sure this Perl one-liner would have been enough: `perl -ne '@m = /(?:(\w+)\W+)(?:(dot)\W+(\w+)\W+)*?(at)\W+(\w+)\W+(?:(dot)\W+(\w+)\W+)*?(dot)\W+(com)/;  for(@m) { s/^at$/@/; s/^dot$/./; print; }'`

Comment: @IMSoP: Yeah. I'm just saying, back then I'm not sure they'd started bothering yet. :-)

Comment: This was my response to someone who asked for my personal e-mail. "The purpose of SO is have a Q&A site for the benefit of the community. I think it's better to allow the community access to any communications regarding this question and answer."

Answer (score 7):

I would say this is not really what Stack Overflow is about and comments asking for such information should be flagged (as "not constructive" probably).

If you want people to contact you, you're free to say this in your profile and provide appropriate contact details (and probably also say what type of contact you want, e.g. social or work-related) (keep in mind that making your contact details publicly available always entails some risk, depending on what you share).